# Cannot run jar file. Cannot find org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I already have org.apache.commons.lang3.jar in my project

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But after i export to .jar, i cannot run it

[image]

I can run it in my IDE(Eclipse). I can run it if i export using the "Runnable JAR File" option, but i want to export using the "JAR File" option, as it is smaller in MB, so that i can send to my colleague through email.

Comment: The jar is smaller because it leaves out all the other jars you are using. When you run the code you have to tell java where to find those jars using the classpath `-cp` command line option. The person you email will also have to find all those jars.

Comment: @greg-449 possible to do it such I just have to double click the jar file?

Comment: That is what the Runnable Jar is for, it is larger because it contains all the jars necessary. Being able to double click the jar depends on which operating system you are using.